# Possible security vulnerabilities with running a local server alongside a web application

Tags: web-application

I have a web application which has a small subset of users who need to read data from various places on their desktop (e.g. a serial port) and send that data to the browser session to process and then store.

One way that I'm considering accomplishing this goal is by writing a very small desktop application that would act as a web server running on localhost, which the web browser could request information from.  The desktop application would then fetch the resource and send it back to the browser.

If the desktop application checks to ensure that any incoming connections are actually from a loopback address, adds a CORs header to ensure that requests are coming from the correct browser session, and exchanges a shared secret with the web browser, are there any other security concerns with this setup?

In my research, I have encountered several threads of people who say that it would leave you open to exploits, but I haven't seen anyone outline specific vulnerabilities. The only possible abuses that I can think of involve the possible attacker having physical access to the machine, at which point they could read from the serial port themselves.

Comment: *"exchanges a shared secret with the web browser"* - how is this exactly done? Specifically is this process sufficiently protected against CSRF and XSS attacks? Also note that CORS headers don't necessarily prevent a cross-site request, they primarily prevent cross-site reading (and non-simple requests).

Comment: The secret would be exchanged as a header which would need to be explicitly set.  Since it would be requesting a resource at "localhost:{port}", the browser wouldn't be sending any of the actual applications cookies and the secret in the header should sufficiently protect from CSRF.  In addition, all requests would be POST and application/json, which would assist CORS in preventing other domains from reading values from the local server.

Comment: So the shared secret is in the client side of the application and thus potentially accessible and open for misuse by XSS?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that I see the distinction between "an attacker can read a token and use that to make privileged API calls" and "an attacker can execute a script that makes a privileged API call in the page."  If there's an XSS vulnerability on a site, any privileged APIs the user has access to can be accessed by the attacker, whether or not they can directly read the token.  Or to put it another way - if the site already has an XSS vulnerability, then security has failed elsewhere.

Comment: First, you asked for vulnerabilities and it looks like this is one in your design. And if you use a fixed shared token between web application and local server you are right. But if the token is for example created by the remote server and only valid for a specific action and signed by the server, then it can only be used for this action no matter if XSS or not. So it depends on where the logic resides on what a valid action is and how it gets enforced.

Comment: That's true. I think that in this particular case, having a general XSS vulnerability would cause more damage than if someone just obtained the token.  For them to use the token outside of that particular browser session, they would also need to be able to execute requests locally (due to the localhost restriction).  So if an XSS vulnerability does occur, the damage would likely not be because of someone stealing the token.  That is a good thing to consider though.